# Jmeter load testing giving different values

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

when I am load testing for 100 users at rampup of 2 seconds I am getting different values for same users and same ramp up time why is this happening can anyone help?

in remote server
1st time
summary =    100 in 00:00:03 =   31.7/s Avg:  1916 Min:   985 Max:  2737 Err:     0 (0.00%)

2nd time
summary +      1 in 00:00:01 =    1.5/s Avg:   260 Min:   260 Max:   260 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 22 Started: 22 Finished: 0
summary +     99 in 00:00:02 =   65.6/s Avg:   113 Min:    18 Max:   371 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 0 Started: 100 Finished: 100
summary =    100 in 00:00:02 =   45.9/s Avg:   114 Min:    18 Max:   371 Err:     0 (0.00%)

3rd time
summary +      1 in 00:00:01 =    2.0/s Avg:    92 Min:    92 Max:    92 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 14 Started: 14 Finished: 0
summary +     99 in 00:00:02 =   58.7/s Avg:    26 Min:    13 Max:    92 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 0 Started: 100 Finished: 100
summary =    100 in 00:00:02 =   45.5/s Avg:    26 Min:    13 Max:    92 Err:     0 (0.00%)

Answer (score 0):

Normally tests should be [repeatable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeatability) which means that re-running the test should produce the same results.

Your test case is kind of specific, it looks like a [spike test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Spike_testing), for the first time response times are quite high and 2nd and 3rd execution they're going down. I can think of the following possible reasons:

- First time response times are high because [caches are not warmed up](https://www.payoda.com/cache-warming/)
- Your application might have some optimization mechanisms like [JIT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/underst_jit.html)
- If you run exactly the same test it might be the case your system under test [caches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)) responses in different levels (operating system memory, database query cache, 3rd-party solutions like [memcached](https://memcached.org/)

In order to have more repeatable results and better picture I would suggest:

- increasing your test duration to i.e. 10 minutes
- [increasing your load gradually](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-period), i.e. change ramp-up time to 5 minutes
- implementing monitoring of the system under test using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/)